# class implements interface yet flow says "this type is incompatible"

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I' ve tried this with flow-bin `0.57.3` and `0.59.0`

[flowtype.org/try code](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVBLAdgFwKYBOUAhgMZ5gCSAEnDACaEA8AynALZ4AqAngA54AfGDABvVCJEBzDADc8ACgCUALjBtOvAQG5UAX3SkYxAM4mwAQVoNCAeSgA5AK7sARoTAZ2fGHk65zGjpGAiYsF3cCYXFJMBl5ZTVwtw8Y2MkCPBwnAiwwABYAJl1YgwNUHH4KADEnLFIcDDgsLgALYhwAVRM8Eytg5g1uKuEAXjAFAA81IJtQoa0hJVHBWTgMel1UKDqGpryoODgpsDV+uftnFIIlMT0wYGAwejgwLDgcVuwpABowT4w5kBYAAVk4TDgwMQ8nhJsRvL50ApDq81LV6o1mm0Ot1eucQmEIoRBEogA)

I am defining an interface for classes that hold things:

```
interface IHolder<SomeType>  {
    give(): SomeType;
}
```

I am now defining a class that implements this interface:

```
class AHolderOfNumber implements IHolder<number> {
    give(): number {
        return 42;
    }
}
```

I am now defining a type for functions that make use of such holders of things:

```
type FunctionThatUsesAHolder<SomeType> = (x: IHolder<SomeType>)=>void;
```

I am now defining a function that makes use of a `AHolderOfNumber`:

```
function foo(x : AHolderOfNumber) {} // do nothing, this is just an example
```

So far so good and everything type-checks.

In my book, since class `AHolderOfNumber` implements `IHolder<number>` then it should follow that function `foo` is of type `FunctionThatUsesAHolder<number>`.

Yet the below line fails to type-check:

```
(foo : FunctionThatUsesAHolder<number>)
```

Flow complains with:

```
Error: src/example.js:69
 69: (foo : FunctionThatUsesAHolder<number>)
      ^^^^ function. This type is incompatible with
 69: (foo : FunctionThatUsesAHolder<number>)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ function type
  This parameter is incompatible:
     57: type FunctionThatUsesAHolder<SomeType> = (x: IHolder<SomeType>)=>void;
                                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ IHolder. This type is incompatible with
     65: function foo(x : AHolderOfNumber) {
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ AHolderOfNumber


Found 1 error
```

What gives?

Comment: Generally a functional example on http://flowtype.org/try helps a lot for Flow questions, since people can play with the code.

Comment: @loganfsmyth didn't know about https://flow.org/try/. That's awesome. Just added link at beginning of post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So actually the question is: why `(AHolderOfNumber) => void` is not compatible with `(IHolder<number>) => void`?

Let's assume that `AHolderOfNumber` has additional method `bar` and function `foo` looks something like:

```
class AHolderOfNumber implements IHolder<number> {
    give(): number {
        return 42;
    }

    bar() {
    }
}

function foo(x : AHolderOfNumber) {
    x.bar()
}
```

If flow would allow you to cast function `foo` to function that requires less specific parameter, you could get a runtime error if you'd pass `IHolder<number>` implementation without `bar` method:

```
class BHolderOfNumber implements IHolder<number> {
    give(): number {
        return 11;
    }
}

const requiresLessSpecific = (foo : (IHolder<number>)=>void);

let bHolder = new BHolderOfNumber();
requiresLessSpecific(bHolder); //runtime error
```

More info about type variance [here](https://flow.org/en/docs/lang/variance/)